# Buttons not working

Tags: jquery

I have following files that are added to header:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/prototype.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/scriptaculous.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.1.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
     jQuery.noConflict();          
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.alphanumeric.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.friends.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.colorbox.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
     jQuery.noConflict();          
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/site.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/search.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/settings.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/inbox.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/profile.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/color_picker.js"></script>
<?php if($CONFIG['fb_status'] == 1) { ?>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/facebook.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  facebook_appId = "<?php print($CONFIG['fb_appId']); ?>";
  faceboook_base = "<?php print($CONFIG['site_url']); ?>";

</script>

<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    //Examples of how to assign the ColorBox event to elements
    jQuery(".example5").colorbox({
        onComplete:function(){ document.getElementById('question1').value=document.getElementById('question').value; }
    });

});
</script>
```

I have been placing noconflict on differnt places but for some reason one of the jquery buttons dont work. Is there any way i can put noconflict or use anything else that will make all these files work?

Comment: hi Ken!  try to remember to put your code blocks inside a code tag.  it's the button that looks like {}!   makes it a lot easier for us to read :)

Comment: It would be easier to help if you could remove the PHP specific code as non-PHP people could then help you with your issue- I'm a jQuery/Java user I don't see anything PHP specific about your question and would love to help but the PHP code is preventing me.

Comment: There is only one line of PHP code. You can even ignore it. But the question here is what can i do to make all those jQuery's , prototype and other files work together?

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript" src="js/facebook.js"></script>` move this line below the next tag because the api key might need to be set before it carries on other instructions.

Answer (score 0):

you have started

`<?php if($CONFIG['fb_status'] == 1) { ?>`

but not ended it, will show a php Fatal erro and break down.

Btw why so many script files, I bet half of them are not even used most of the time, It must take your website a decade to load :)

Comment: No they are all being used. Site loads quickly. I have not written whole code here. Its just the part i had question about.